# Microservice subscript to subtenant REST Endpoint not working

Tags: cumulocity

I deployed my microservice over master tenant and subscript it onlty to subtenant.

If I call:
GET https://subtenant.cumulocity.com/service/mymicroservice/health i get Status Code 200 and UP

However if I call:
GET https://subtenant.cumulocity.com/service/mymicroservice/myendpoint/data
 I get Status Code 500 and

```
{
"timestamp": 1534235792950,
"status": 500,
"error": "Internal Server Error",
"exception": "com.cumulocity.sdk.client.SDKException",
"message": "Http status code: 403\n{error=\"security/Forbidden\",message=\"Access is denied\",info=\"https://www.cumulocity.com/guides/reference-guide/#error_reporting\",details=\"null\"}",
"path": "/ mymicroservice /data"
```

}

When I subscribe to the master tenant, the microservice is working fine! It seems that the user of subtenant is not allowed to access the Cumulocity API… I also checked the user and the role. The access rights are all granted. How can i access my microservice at subtenants?

Answer (score 1):

I solved the problem by my self. I made a mistake; i forgot to add a role to the manifest to requiredRoles. It was also not working in master tenant.